# How do I add a podcast show to my Library without subscribing?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts

The latest update of Apple Podcasts (on iOS 14.5) removed a ton of shows from my Library. It appears to have kept only the ones I was actively subscribed to.

But I have many shows that I like to listen to occasionally without downloading and being notified about every episode. How can I manage these on the new podcasts app? The only method I can see at the moment is to remember exactly all the shows I like, manually search them out, download an episode, then play it from the Downloads section (because they don’t even go to Up Next).

Comment: There is a free podcast app called Overcast that lets you do just that. I gave up on the Apple podcast app years ago. Sorry to hear about your ongoing issues.

Comment: I found Overcast to be extremely buggy and unintuitive (not to mention the developer has some very strange ideas).  I use Pocket Casts and it allows you to add your own files, like you want to do.  It also has a bunch of features that makes listening to podcasts more enjoyable, it's worth checking out.